# xades4j validation error: SigningCertificate property contains one or more certificates that are not part of the certification path

Tags: verification, xades4j

I get a SigningCertificateCertsNotInCertPathException when validating a XADES. The file is signed using a certificate what has a intermediate cert and a root cert:

The section xades:SigningCertificate in the XADES file contains the tree certs. If I build the XADES with only the personal cert in xades:SigningCertificate (using false in FileSystemKeyStoreKeyingDataProvider.returnFullChain), the validation run Ok, but not with the tree certs in xades:SigningCertificate...

Debugging the library, I see that certChainData.getCertificateChain() in method 'verify' of SigningCertificateVerifier.java only contains 2 certs: personal and intermediate certs, but no root cert. I think this could be the reason why SigningCertificateCertsNotInCertPathException arise, but really I don't know

How must I validate the XADES with the tree certs in the xades:SigningCertificate section? My code is this:

```
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse(new InputSource(new FileReader(SIGNED)));
        DOMHelper.useIdAsXmlId(doc.getDocumentElement());

        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagNameNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#", "Signature");

        FileSystemDirectoryCertStore certStore = new FileSystemDirectoryCertStore(CERT_FOLDER);

        KeyStore ks;
        try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(CERT_FOLDER + KEY_STORE)) {
            ks = KeyStore.getInstance("jks");
            ks.load(fis, PASS.toCharArray());
        }

        CertificateValidationProvider provider = new PKIXCertificateValidationProvider(
                ks, false, certStore.getStore());
        XadesVerificationProfile profile = new XadesVerificationProfile(provider);
        Element sigElem = (Element) nl.item(0);
        
        XAdESVerificationResult r = profile.newVerifier().verify(sigElem, null);
```

In CERT_FOLDER, I have the two .cer files (root and intermediate certs)

In the KEY_STORE file, I have the three certificates:

```
Tipo de Almacén de Claves: PKCS12
Proveedor de Almacén de Claves: SUN
Su almacén de claves contiene 3 entradas
  personal, 09-dic-2021, PrivateKeyEntry,
  Huella Digital de Certificado (SHA1): D8:25:0E:AA:...
  intermedio, 09-dic-2021, trustedCertEntry,
  Huella Digital de Certificado (SHA1): 80:8B:72:E4:...
  raiz, 09-dic-2021, trustedCertEntry,
  Huella Digital de Certificado (SHA1): EC:50:35:07:...
```

Answer (score 0):

If the intermediate certificate is also on the trusted key store (`ks`) supplied to `PKIXCertificateValidationProvider` , then you're saying that it can be used as a trust root. During verification, it will be possible to build a certification path consisting of `personal` < `intermedio`, as the later is trusted, so no need to keep going.

If your trust root is `raiz`, then `ks` should only contain this certificate.

Comment: Indeed, that was the problem. Putting only the root certificate in the KeyStore the validation works correctly. I don't know why, I thought it was necessary to put the personal certificate in the KeyStore, and incidentally, also the intermediate one ...
Thank you very much for the help!